# How to dynamically resize Leaflet CRS.Simple map based on viewport while maintaining standardized coordinates?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet to render a static image as a map. For the sake of example, let's say the image is 700px x 700px.

To create the map, I do the following:

```
map.current = L.map("map", {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    dragging: false,
    doubleClickZoom: false,
    touchZoom: false,
    scrollWheelZoom: false,
    boxZoom: false,
    keyboard: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    attributionControl: false,
  });

// imageHeight and imageWidth are already loaded from backend (in px):
// So in this case, they're 700 and 700, respectively
var bounds = [
    [0, 0],
    [imageHeight, imageWidth],
  ];

  L.imageOverlay(
    `${baseUrl}/uploads/images/${propertyData.image}`,
    bounds
  ).addTo(map.current);
  map.current.fitBounds(bounds);
```

The issue is, this renders in a 700 x 700 image, even if the viewport is 500px wide.

One workaround I had tried was essentially taking the viewport width and height and changing the bounds so that they were <= the viewport width and height (while maintaining the aspect ratio). This makes the image render in at an appropriate size, but it also has the unwanted side effect of changing the coordinates (since bounds are different). So now, if I want to store coordinates in the DB, I have to go through the process of standardizing them so that they display the same across all viewports.

While this approach works alright, it's a hacky way of doing it and leads to a lot of seemingly unnecessary code, and I'm virtually certain Leaflet has a built-in way of doing this, I just can't seem to find it in the docs.

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks!